# Как отправить результат выполнения скрипта в отдельный текстовый файл?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

допустим существует некоторое количество скриптов, задача которых что то смотреть на сайте. Результат просмотра должен отправляться в текстовые документ или вообще хоть куда-то, что бы можно было это задокументировать. Как и с помощью чего это можно сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для отправки чего-либо со страницы нужен ajax, но он не позволит записать отправленное в файловую систему, он может только передать данные скрипту на сервер (на php, например), который запишет это уже в файл.

Еще вариант формировать файл для скачивания при помощи того-же ajax и инициировать загрузку текущему пользователю.